# Can I map two entities to two different tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF and Code First. I try to map two entities to two different tables.
First of all I try to map Material to the table Materials and secondly I try to map PlannedMaterial to both Materials and ScheduleRows.

One ScheduleRow needs to have a Foreigtn key to a row in the Materials table. There no foreign key from Materials table to ScheduleRows table.

These are my entities.

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // from material table
    public string Name { get; set; }  // from material table

    // public PlannedMaterial PlannedMaterial { get; set; } Do I need this? I don't want a relation from this side.
}

public class PlannedMaterial
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // from *ScheduleRow table*
    public string Name { get; set; } // from *material table*
    public int SequenceNo { get; set; } // from *ScheduleRow* table

    public Material Material { get; set; } // Do I need this? I'm only interrested in the Name column from the material table
}
```

And these are my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RunScheduleRow](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Material_id] [int] NOT NULL)  -- FK to Material table


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Material](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
```

I want to do this mapping using the fluent API in OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder). Is it possible? How?

I appreciate all ideas and suggestions.

Comment: the fact that you are showing SQL tables, kindof goes against the concept of code first.¨

Answer (score 0):

I think yor design is not good. You try to manage relation between ScheduleRow and Material Tables, but this relation  can be managed by entity framwork.

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // from material table
    public string Name { get; set; }  // from material table
   public ICollection<ScheduleRow> ScheduleRows{ get; set; }

}

public class ScheduleRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // from *ScheduleRow table*
      public int SequenceNo { get; set; } // from *ScheduleRow* table

    public Material  Material { get; set; } 
}
```

configure your shcema

```
public class YourContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext(): base() 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ScheduleRow> ScheduleRows { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure default schema
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YourShema");
    }
}
```

Map entity to tables

namespace CodeFirst_FluentAPI_Tutorials
{

```
 public class YourContext: DbContext 
    {
        public YourDBContext(): base() 
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ScheduleRow> ScheduleRows { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                //Configure default schema
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YourSchema");

            //Map entity to table
            modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().ToTable("Material");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ScheduleRow>().ToTable("RunScheduleRow","dbo");

        }
    }
}
```

To configure your columns name, you add this instruction to your context

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
                    .Property(p => p.propertyname)
                    .HasColumnName("Caolum_name")
                    .HasColumnOrder(your_column_order)
                    .HasColumnType("column_type");
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you skip to the solution, read this, it will shed some light on what EF entities are user for and as, because I can promise you it's not what you think it is.

**Rules of EF:**

1. EF entities like you classes must be convertible to a SQL table.
2. Same goes for data links from other objects. for an example if you make your own type, that will not be natively supported.
3. Same goes for queries. in EF the list types used are mostly IEnumerable (Read only) and ICollection (Read/write). Using arrays and Lists and such is acceptible if you are never to publish back to the database again.¨

**So what are you missing?**
You my good sir, are missing Rule no 1. so you must make a soft entity (regular DTO/Model/Class)

kindof like this. but be aware, now PlannedMaterial is not saved anywhere.

```
public class PlannedMaterial
{
    public PlannedMaterial(ScheduleRow s, Material m){
        ScheduleRow = s;
        Material = m;
    }
    public int Id { get{return _s.Id; } set{_s.Id = value;} }
    public string Name { get{return _m.Name; } set{_m.Name = value; }
    public int SequenceNo { get{return _s.SequenceNo; } set{_s.SequenceNo = value; } 

    Material _m{ get; set; }
    ScheduleRow _s{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is how to do your Entities

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ScheduleRow> ScheduleRows { get; set; } 
}

public class ScheduleRow 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNo { get; set; }

    public virtual Material Material { get; set; } 
}
```

Context (see the builder)

```
public class YourContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext(): base() 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ScheduleRow> ScheduleRows { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Fluent API
        modelBuilder.Entity<Material>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ScheduleRow)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Material)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Links:
[FluentAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)